# Show computer's screen on another computer

Tags: screen-sharing

I have two computers I use for giving presentations because the computer attached to the projector is in a different physical location from my notes.  Is there a way to send a live image of the projector's computer to my notes computer?  The presentation computer is Windows 10, the notes computer is OS X, but a VM can run windows if needed.

Answer (score 2):

On the windows 10 computer, install tightvnc - ensure you give it a password during install. once installed hover the mouse over the vnc server icon bottom right to get your IP address. Remember the password.

On the mac open safari and type 'vnc://win10 vnc IP address'

Press Enter. Type the password. You should now see the Win10 presentation computer.